# Invoke method before annotated another one

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm trying to add functionality into an interface method signature by using annotations.

the idea is to invoke some another methods fore each annotated one.

for example if I have this method signature:

```
public interface IMyInterface{

    @Entity(visibileName = "Name")
    public TextField getName();
}
```

I need to invoke a method that print the string name before, after this method.
also if their is any way to define a functionality to this method on run time.

I'm also opened to structural changes.

Comment: I'm not sure if all what you try to accomplish can be done this way, but you might have a look at AOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is annotating `interface` methods, than **it is** possible without AOP.
Just use *Dynamic Proxies*!

The base `interface` to implement a proxy is `InvocationHandler`

> InvocationHandler is the interface implemented by the invocation
>   handler of a proxy instance.

---

Follow in-code comments.

```
static class MyInterfaceProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    private static final Map<String, Method> METHODS = new HashMap<>(16);

    static {
        // Scan each interface method for the specific annotation
        // and save each compatible method
        for (final Method m : IMyInterface.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.getAnnotation(YourAnnotation.class) != null) {
                METHODS.put(m.getName(), m);
            }
        }
    }

    private final IMyInterface toBeProxied;

    private MyInterfaceProxy(final IMyInterface toBeProxied) {
        // Accept the real implementation to be proxied
        this.toBeProxied = toBeProxied;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(
            final Object proxy,
            final Method method,
            final Object[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        // A method on MyInterface has been called!
        // Check if we need to call it directly or if we need to
        // execute something else before!
        final Method found = METHODS.get(method.getName());

        if (found != null) {
            // The method exist in our to-be-proxied list
            // Execute something and the call it
            // ... some other things
            System.out.println("Something else");
        }

        // Invoke original method
        return method.invoke(toBeProxied, args);
    }
}
```

To use this `InvocationHandler` implementation you need a real instance of the object to be proxied.

Say you have a *Factory* for `MyInterface` implementations

```
MyInterface getMyInsterface() {
   ...
   final MyInterface instance = ...

   // Create the proxy and inject the real implementation
   final IMyInterface proxy = (IMyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        MyInterfaceProxy.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] {IMyInterface.class},
        new MyInterfaceProxy(instance) // Inject the real instance
    );

   // Return the proxy!
   return proxy;
}
```

Comment: Proxy.newProxyInstance, can you give me full implementation for this method?    what the full qualified name for this class, what is the jar file?

Comment: @AliTaha It's a standard method in the JDK. It's already done!